# How to delimit fixed width text file based upon column number

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have text file which is fixed width. I need to delimit the contents based upon the Column number ( Column 100-120 ) into a variable and need to check length of the variable.

There are chance that variable has more than 20 character and i need to remove that particular line

Eg :

```
0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
short_name          des_shrt                              px
BOS1111             ALTIC 6.62 2_23                       106.37500000
BOS2222             AMA                                   47.26000000
BOS3333             AMB                                   12.898000
BOS4444             AMEX Express                          10.09780000
BOS5555             BBC                                   111.2233
BOS6666             CNN                                   123.123445
BOS7777             STACK OVERFLOW                        344.9090
BOS8888             STACT 12.0 2/1988                     10.99999999
BOS9999             ABC                                   20
```

Output :

```
px  
106.375  
47.26  
12.898  
10.0978  
111.2233  
123.123445  
344.909  
10.99999999       -> it exceeds 10 digit and should throw error  
20
```

Comment: You are not really working under MS-DOS, are you? It is Windows, right? Anyway, please share what you have tried so far and what you have problems with! Otherwise, this question appears as a code request, which is off-topic here. Please learn [ask] here! And your sample data does contain any data in columns 100 to 120, and I cannot see any field exceeding 20 characters...

Comment: please [edit] your question and place the information there!

Comment: Where is the powershell coding, it was being removed from here

Comment: someone has removed the powershell coding. Can i have it back

Comment: Get-Content $FileName | Where-Object { 

$Number=(-join $_[$StartColumn..$EndColumn]).Trim()

([string](1000 * $Number)).Length -gt 12

} | Set-Content $WORK\Powershelloutput.txt  getting below error.,Cannot convert value "x" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At P:\Share\script.ps1:11 char:1
+ ([string](1000 * $Number)).Length -gt 12
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToIntege

Comment: $Number=(-join $_[$StartColumn..$EndColumn]).TrimEnd(' 0') if i use like this getting below error, Cannot convert value "." to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At P:\Share\script.ps1:11 char:1
+ ([string](1000 * $Number)).Length -gt 12
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution – see all the explanatory remarks in the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FULL_LINES_OUT=#"

rem // Initialise variables:
set "HEAD=#"
rem // Read text file line by line:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%~1") do (
    rem // Store current line into environment variable:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Extract 12 characters at character position 58:
    set "LINE=!LINE:~58,12!"
    rem // Remove trailing spaces, if any:
    for /F %%K in ("!LINE!") do set "LINE=%%K"
    rem // Check whether line is the first one (header):
    if defined HEAD (
        rem // Return header line:
        if defined _FULL_LINES_OUT (echo %%L) else (echo !LINE!)
        set "HEAD="
    ) else (
        rem // Split numbers into integer and fractional parts:
        for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%I in ("!LINE!") do (
            set "INT=%%I" & set "FRACT=%%J"
        )
        rem // Remove trailing zeros from fractional part:
        set "FLAG=#"
        for /L %%J in (1,1,12) do (
            if defined FLAG (
                if "!FRACT:~-1!"=="0" (
                    set "FRACT=!FRACT:~,-1!"
                ) else (
                    set "FLAG="
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Reassemble truncated decimal number:
        if defined FRACT (
            set "LINE=!INT!.!FRACT!"
        ) else (
            set "LINE=!INT!"
        )
        rem // Check whether string length of number exceeds 10:
        if not "!LINE:~10!"=="" (
            rem // Number is longer than 10 characters:
            >&2 (if defined _FULL_LINES_OUT (echo %%L) else (echo !LINE!))
        ) else (
            rem // Number is not too long, so return original line:
            if defined _FULL_LINES_OUT (echo %%L) else (echo !LINE!)
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Supposing you name the script `check-px-numbers.bat` and your data file is called `D:\Data\data.txt`, run the script like this:

```cmd
check-px-numbers.bat "D:\Data\data.txt" 2> nul
```

To write the output into another file `D:\Data\filtered.txt`, call the script like this:

```cmd
check-px-numbers.bat "D:\Data\data.txt" > "D:\Data\filtered.txt"
```

This would return the following output file when using your sample data:

> ```cmd
> short_name          des_shrt                              px
> BOS1111             ALTIC 6.62 2_23                       106.37500000
> BOS2222             AMA                                   47.26000000
> BOS3333             AMB                                   12.898000
> BOS4444             AMEX Express                          10.09780000
> BOS5555             BBC                                   111.2233
> BOS6666             CNN                                   123.123445
> BOS7777             STACK OVERFLOW                        344.9090
> BOS9999             ABC                                   20
> ```

And the following error message would appear in the console window:

> ```cmd
> BOS8888             STACT 12.0 2/1988                     10.99999999
> ```

Change the line `set "_FULL_LINES_OUT=#"` to `set "_FULL_LINES_OUT="` (or remove it) if you want your output data to look like this:

> ```cmd
> px
> 106.375
> 47.26
> 12.898
> 10.0978
> 111.2233
> 123.123445
> 344.909
> 20
> ```

In case you want to overwrite the original file, you need to do that in two steps:

```cmd
check-px-numbers.bat "D:\Data\data.txt" > "D:\Data\filtered.txt"
> nul move /Y "D:\Data\filtered.txt" "D:\Data\data.txt"
```

To write the erroneous lines into a file, use this:

```cmd
check-px-numbers.bat "D:\Data\data.txt" 2> "D:\Data\errors.txt"
```

You can combine this to write the filtered and the error lines at once like this:

```cmd
check-px-numbers.bat "D:\Data\data.txt" > "D:\Data\filtered.txt" 2> "D:\Data\errors.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks aschipfl. The above coding is not eliminating the error row. We need to remove the error row from the data file or need to create a new file for the error row

Comment: Also additionally if the PX value is multplied by 1000 and it should not exceed 12digits as well.

Comment: Did you read the whole answer? I described how you get the output written in files. And please do not change the requirements as you violate already available answers then; note that batch is not capable of floating-point arithmetics...

Comment: I slightly changed the script so you can write erroneous data lines into a file too...

Comment: thanks aschipfl for your answers. I have read the whole answer and tried it. Is there any way to calculate the PX value * 1000 and send it to output.

Comment: No, but you can work around that by moving the decimal separator three positions to the right, by string manipulation...

Comment: hi hipfl the above code works but if we have another field after it is printing entire file in new file. Can u help with that

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to say. Do you mean there is another data column behind the `px` column? If so, I don't see a reason why the code should not work, but I can't try at the moment; I'll let you know as soon as I can...

Comment: yes we need to add another column and code is not working if we add another field

Comment: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_FULL_LINES_OUT=#"
set "HEAD=#"
rem // Read text file line by line:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%~1") do (
    rem // Store current line into environment variable:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Extract 20 characters at character position 101:
    set "LINE=!LINE:~100,20!"
    rem // Remove trailing spaces, if any:
    for /F %%K in ("!LINE!") do set "LINE=%%K"
   
if not "!LINE:~16!"=="" (
    rem // Number is longer than 16 characters:
    >&2 (if defined _FULL_LINES_OUT (echo %%L) else (echo !LINE!))
)
)
endlocal

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, when I append another data column, it works just fine. Perhaps you did not adapt the character positions correctly...

Comment: set "LINE=10000*!LINE!" tried to before final if statement but it lists complete file content
if not "!LINE:~12!"=="" (
            rem // Number is longer than 12 characters:
            >&2 (if defined _FULL_LINES_OUT (echo %%L) else (echo !LINE!))
But not the desired output

Comment: As I told you batch files do not support floating-point arithmetics; even it you added the missing `/A` option to `set "LINE=10000*!LINE!"`, it would through an error `Missing operator.` as the decimal point `.` is not understood, and the result would be just the integer part multiplied by `10000`; I recommend to insert some `ECHO` commands for experiments like that, so you can see what actually happens, for example: `ECHO 10000*LINE=!LINE!`...

Comment: So what is the solution to do arithmatics in batch files.

Comment: Multiplying with integer powers of 10 (like 1000 or 10000) is nothing but moving the decimal point around; this can be done using [string manipulation](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html); the code already splits the numbers in integer and fractional parts, so move the last few digits of the integer part to the beginning of the fractional part, or vice versa; for true floating-point multiplications, you either have to write your own multiplication routine (like you would do it on paper), or you "borrow" arithmetic functions from another language...